# Can't seem to use "su" in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, su

I installed Arch Linux through the Zen installer, simply because I felt lazy.
During the installation, the setup wizard asked me for a root password, and I never entered one, thinking it would use my user's password if one wasn't set.

Now, I attempted to run `su` to gain root, and it says

```
su: failed to execute /usr/bin/: Permission denied
```

And I've already tried to run `sudo passwd root`
and then run `su`, enter the password, and it still has the same output. ran `chmod 755` for `/`, `/bin`, and `/lib`
And I can't think of anything else to do.

Comment: I believe your user is not in the sudoers group. Give us the output of the following commands: groups, sudo -ll

Comment: What does `getent passwd root` show you? It sounds like a bad shell configuration, though I haven't managed to replicate it exactly.

Comment: @vfbsilva 1) the question is about `su`, not `sudo`; 2) `sudo` clearly did work when used.

Comment: Does the error message actually say that you failed to execute a directory?

Comment: Looks to me like root's shell got set to `/usr/bin/`. Try `su -s /bin/bash` (assuming your bash is in /bin).

Comment: Could be your already messed up filesystem permission, can you give complete output with `strace` and what is there in audit log file?

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue. There is a bug in the installer that sets the root shell to /usr/bin/

https://github.com/spookykidmm/zen_installer/issues/2

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash root #this should fix, if your user has sudo
su -s /bin/bash - # or specify the shell in su
```